# Download only the first page of a pdf programmatically (possibly in python)

Tags: python, download, shutil

To download a pdf given its url programmatically, it is possible to use a function like the one below:

```
import urllib
import shulil


def download_pdf(pdf_url, destination_path, timeout_secs=5)
    try:
        req = urllib.request.urlopen(pdf_url, None, timeout_secs)
        with open(destination_path, "wb") as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(req, f)
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f"Exception {e} raised downloading {pdf_url}")
```

As I am interested only in the first page, and I want to speed up the donwload process, is there a way (with `shutil` or in any other way) to download only the first page of a pdf, given its url?

Please note: the aim is to speed up the download, getting only the first page, not to get the whole pdf and then extract the first page.

---

Edit:
An alternative idea can be to download the PDF without the images. This would also speed up the process. Is that possible?

Comment: I’m not too intimately familiar with the PDF format, but that may not be possible necessarily. At the very least you’d need some sort of streaming PDF parser, which may or may not exist. If it doesn’t exist, you’d need to write it on your own, which is probably not worth the effort.

Comment: If your pdf files are sometimes very large, a solution may be to download the first megabyte only, and attempt to parse it. PDF files are sequential and may still open. Try it locally. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, this is probably not a good solution, and not a flexible solution.